# Ubuntu server 14.04 won't boot

Tags: system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu server 14.04 with a USB drive, the setup goes fine but when it tells be to remove the USB and it reboots it fails to boot.

But it boots fine when the USB is in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the hard drive set in the BIOS/UEFI as a boot option? Sounds like maybe it is still trying to boot the USB or otherwise.

Comment: Yes the hdd is set to boot first

Comment: Check the list of the hard drives and see if your motherboard is recognizing the USB or another hard drive as the primary hard drive.

Comment: Yes, it's recognizing the real hdd as a hdd and the USB as a USB

Comment: What motherboard do you have? Have you had trouble booting the hard drive before? Seems strange that after an install it will not even boot to Grub2

Comment: No never had trouble booting before. Also FYI I'm not installing this on a server but an old laptop. A Toshiba Satellite A665-S5170